# Put ENUM values to android spinner?

Tags: android, enums, spinner

For example: I have an enum with days.

How do I put its values into spinner ?

Comment: Keep in mind that the usage of enums within the Android environment is less efficient. If you want to make your code with performance in mind, you should avoid enums according to Android's performance directives.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Serrano, not really actual from android 2.2.

Comment: There was some things that i've found hard to implement without enums.

Comment: Take a look at this answer if you have a different display and value for the array: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37266810/293280

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Some kind of walkthrough is using:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cmbClothType);
mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<MyType>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item, MyType.values()));
```

Answer (score 72):

Similar to another answer, but you can use an ArrayAdapter to populate based on an Enum class. I would recommend overriding toString in the Enum class to make the values populated in the spinner more user friendly.
In the activity:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinnerId);

mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<MyEnum>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MyEnum.values()));
```

Your enum class:

```
public enum MyEnum{
    ENUM1("Enum 1"),
    ENUM2("Enum 2");

    private String friendlyName;

    private MyEnum(String friendlyName){
        this.friendlyName = friendlyName;
    }

    @Override public String toString(){
        return friendlyName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I prefer the other answer, it is great to learn that something like this is possible. +1

Comment: If I want to change the system language, What should I do ?  I cannot initialize like ENUM1("Enum 1");

Comment: @Urchin you could give it a stringResId then... but you have to build your own adapter to get the string from the resId instead of the toString.

Comment: and what if this enum is defined in library module? where is no way how to access string resource without context ? )-:

Answer (score 0):

You can override the toString function in the enum class like other classes and the spinner will read the toString value.

For Ex.

```js
enum class Duration(val value : String) {
  DURATION_HINT("Duration Unit"),
  DAY("Day"),
  WEEK("Week"),
  MONTH("Month");

  override fun toString() : String {
    return value
  }
}
```